# Remove gaps from a list of checkboxes displayed in 3 columns

Tags: css, html

Im populating a list of checkboxes from the databases. And Im trying to display the list 3 columns. But there are gaps between checkboxes where the title of the checkbox is long.

**Example:**

[image]

**My Code:**

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
#skills-label {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #E9E9EF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #F7F8F9;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#skills-label>input {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-margin">
  <div *ngFor="let data of skills">
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
              <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can even out the spaces so there are no gaps? Is that even possible?**

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for above code?

Comment: You can use CSS columns, you can use masonry or pintrest like scripts or you could stretch all items in a row at same height. You have so many options that your question currently qualifies as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing whatsoever to do specifically with checkboxes (tag removed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` on `.uk-margin div` as well.

```
.uk-margin div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
#skills-label {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #E9E9EF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #F7F8F9;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#skills-label>input {
  float: right;
}

.uk-margin div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-margin">
  <div *ngFor="let data of skills">
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
        </label>
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}} {{skill}} {{skill}} {{skill}}{{skill}} {{skill}} {{skill}} {{skill}} {{skill}}
        </label>
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
        </label><label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
        </label>
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
        </label>
    <label id="skills-label" *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(skill, $event.target.checked)"> {{skill}}
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is good! Any chance you know how fill the gaps by pushing the smaller checkboxes into into it?

Comment: You can use `column-count`.

Comment: `column-count` was the one! Thanks for the help!